# Как добавить в TStringList ссылку на другой TStringList?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Необходимо для пары ключ=значение добавить указатель на другой список состоящий из пар.
Пишу

```
var ItemList,item,item1:TStringList;

ItemList := TStringList.Create;
item := TStringList.Create;
item.Add('key1=value1');
ItemList.AddObject('key=value',item);
item1 := ItemList.Objects[ItemList.IndexOfName('key')]; //ошибка
```

При попытке прямого доступа к внутреннему списку не видит методы списка, если присвоить как в последней строке, ругается на несоответствие TObject и TStringList, однако присвоить список как объект (предпоследняя строка) можно, ошибку не выбивает. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

```
item1 := ItemList.Objects[ItemList.IndexOfName('key')] as TStringList;
```

Comment: ERROR: ';' expected прямо перед as. Возможно этот оператор не поддерживается. Есть ещё варианты?

Comment: @Hamster099 оператор поддерживается